Sex identification of two white checkered Skipper butterflies
I have two white checkered skippers and ik for a fact one is a female(at least i think) but im not sure abt the other one? Can some one tell which is which or if there the same sex? One butterfly has a bulkier body with larger wings and wingspan with a smaller head which I believe that one's a female the other one has a smaller body smaller Wings in a bigger head which I believe to be a male but I'm not sure can somebody help me sorry about the picture quality my phone takes bad pictures

It’s “sex”, not “gender”, and we use standard English, not textese on this site, the details of which you are expected to read about by finishing the [Tour].

Any sex determination here would be speculation.
Butterflies and Moths of North America has this to say about Burnsius albezens. Note the bolded last sentence:

Identification: Paler than Pyrgus communis. Male often has complete black checks in wing fringes. Upperside of male is blue-gray; female is black. Both sexes have large white spots which form median bands across both wings. Male has a costal fold enclosing scent scales on the upperside of the forewing. Underside is dull white with dark gray bands. Positive identification can be made only by dissection and scrutiny of the male genitalia.

